# Purchasing multiple items/multi quantity of item in one transaction with android billing library

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

According to the documentation of Android billing library v4.0+, google has added the ability to purchase multi-quantity of an item.

I enabled the option in Play Console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ6OA.png

But unfortunately the dialog won't allow me to select quantity:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQEzA.png

the invoking code looks like this:

```html
        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                                     List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "billingDebug: size" + skuDetailsList.size());

                        if (skuDetailsList.size() > 0){
                            BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0))


                                    .build();
                            String responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(DetailActivity.this, billingFlowParams).toString();
                            Log.d(TAG, "billingDebug: response: " + responseCode);
                        }



                    }
        });
```

How can i use the billing library to purchase multiple SKUs / multi quantity of a single SKU?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but how did you enable the multi-quantity; after updating to billing lib v5,  I can't check that option it's disabled, even when I create a new in-app product.

Comment: I can help you with that @can.do I just had the same issue and talked to the dev team at google. This is the answer  `According to our technical team, the checkbox is disabled since multi-quantity is only enabled when one of the local prices is below multi-quantity thresholds. Please kindly configure the available countries to make sure there are local prices below some regions in the pricing of the in-app product.` After changing the template and set the amount for countries specifically I could activate it. But I now have the same problem as @Jacob Zviagin. So any information on that one?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Avinta.  It seems a template is required, I was trying to set a price directly, once I chose the template it enabled it.  FYI, afterwards, you can choose a direct price (without template) and it remains enabled.  Unfortunately I don't have an answer for the original question, I suggest handling the quantity internally and using it in the purchase -- if that's possible, test and see if the proper quantity is used up. Thanks.